# React Map in functional component Issue

Tags: javascript, reactjs

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-h39zlx?file=/src/App.tsx

how to use react map for below link , line number 31 in App.tsx ?

```
 const Tabs = [
      {
        tabname: "tab2"
      },
      {
        tabname: "tab3"
      },
      {
        tabname: "tab4"
      }
    ];
<a to="" className={`tab ${active === "tab2" ? "active" : ""}`} onClick={() => setActive("tab2")}>
Align & Ratio
</a>
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include all relevant information and code. Links to off-site services are fine as supplementary information but everything required to understand your question should be here. See [How to create a Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)

Answer (score -1, accepted):

If linking to an external page that is not a part of your React application, than use `<a>`, else use `<Link>`.
and use "href=" with `<a>` and "to=" with `<Link>`.

```
    {Tabs.map((obj, i) => (
      <p key={i} onClick={() => setActive(obj.tabname)} className="tab">
        {/* Align & Ratio */}
        {obj.tabname}
      </p>
    ))}
```

https://codesandbox.io/s/simple-line-chart-forked-v25zdp?file=/src/App.tsx